# Identifying the subject of a complicated sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects

This sentence took me a lot of time to parse:

> For migrant birds, which habitats are suitable during the non-breeding
>   season influences habitat availability, population resilience to
>   habitat loss, and ultimately survival.

<sub>(from Blackburn, E. and Cresswell, W. (2015), [“Fine-scale habitat use during the non-breeding season suggests that winter habitat does not limit breeding populations of a declining long-distance Palearctic migrant”](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jav.00738/abstract). *Journal of Avian Biology*, 46: 622–633. doi: 10.1111/jav.00738)</sub>

Finally I figured out that the predicate is *influences* and the subject is hidden somewhere behind the *"which*. But is this correct English? What is the subject of this sentence then?

Comment: That's an awful sentence. I think *influences* is the main verb, with three objects, and the subject is "which habitats are suitable". That is, "the choice of suitable habitats" or something similar.

Comment: @AndrewLeach and the habitat suitability influences the 3 things (availability, resilience and survival), or is influenced by those? I guess the former is the case...

Comment: @AndrewLeach Can an adjective clause be also the subject of the main clause? I mean, that's what the author probably meant, but it is more than awful—it's completely agrammatical, right?

Comment: @Yay - It's not an adjective clause, *even though its juxtaposition to "birds" in what looks deceptively like a parenthetical structure makes it seem like one for a confusing moment*.  The subject of the sentence is a noun clause led by the relative pronoun.  Andrew Leach is right on the money: **it's a wretched sentence.** It's grammatically consistent, though.

Comment: @Yay It's completely grammatical and also there's nothing wrong with it as a piece of technical biology writing.

Comment: I was just reading about [garden path sentences](http://www.fun-with-words.com/ambiguous_garden_path.html) earlier. This fits right in with them. :)

Comment: @Rob_Ster Ooh, I get it now. I thought that *which* was supposed to be a *whose*. Thanks!

Comment: @Araucaria - Could "technical biology writing" be a composition flaw in itself? I sometimes feel that Natural Selection in the STEM part of the jungle favors editors with science savvy over those little bug-eyed English Lanuage Lemurs with their prehensile pronouns and well-subordinated claws.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> For migrant birds, which habitats are suitable during the non-breeding season influences habitat availability, population resilience to habitat loss, and ultimately survival.

This is a sentence from a piece of technical academic writing from the *Journal of Avian Biology*.

The sentence is perfectly grammatical and also makes sense. The structure of the sentence is as follows:

- **Adjunct**: For migrant birds
- **Subject**: which habitats are suitable during the non-breeding season
- **Predicator**: influences
- **Object**: habitat availability, population resilience to habitat loss, and survival.

The Subject is an interrogative content clause. The Object is a coordination of three noun phrases. It has a parenthetical adjunct embedded in it, the word *ultimately*.

The phrase *for birds* is technically an Adjunct just because it isn't a Subject or a Complement of the verb. In terms of information packaging, it has been fronted so that it serves as the topic of the rest of the sentence.

---

<sup>**Grammar note:**</sup>

<sup>Some grammars call Adjuncts *Adverbials*.</sup>

<sup>*Predicator* is that job done by the matrix verb in the clause.</sup>

Comment: I agree that, despite some previous comments, this is a completely straightforward sentence.  It's a little technical.  I also agree that "for migrant birds" is a major sentence part, along with subject and predicate.  But I don't think "adjunct" is a very meaningful term for it.  How about "topic", so we could compare with, e.g., Japanese *wa* phrases?

Comment: @GregLee Have had a little edit. How's that?

Comment: Not good.  A topic is not an adverb, any more than a subject is.

Comment: @GregLee Oh, you meant *Topic* as a fully blown grammatical relations label? (An Adjunct isn't an adverb either, of course). I'm not overly familiar with the term *topic* used as a grammatical relations label (because of my very limited reading around other languages).

Comment: @GregLee Do you consider left-dislocated elements to be Topics?

Comment: No, unlike a left-dislocated element, a Topic needn't have a role within the predicate.  This is what I know about topics (it isn't much): (1) They're important in Japanese.  (2) Jeanette Gundel wrote a dissertation about them.  (3) They are implied by a extended version of Relational Grammar I have worked on (3=indirect object, 2=direct object, 1=subject, 0=topic).